# Asp.NET MVC:Controller checklist error when returning view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

Trying to return 3 lists to the view however, I keep receiving an error about converting system.generic.list to string. It accepts one list but not more than 1. The end goal is to add a checklistbox so I'm following a tutorial I've found online at: [this website](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/creating-simple-checkboxlist-in-mvc-4-using-razor/). Any help would be greatly appreciated

Here is the controller:

```
CronValues cv = new CronValues();

public ActionResult schedulerIndex()
{
    var dayOfMonthList = new List<CronValues>
    {
        new CronValues{DayOfMonth = Convert.ToInt32(Enumerable.Range(1,31).ToList()),IsChecked = false}

    };

    var monthList = new List<CronValues>
    {
        new CronValues{DayOfMonth = Convert.ToInt32(Enum.GetValues(typeof(CronValues.Months))),IsChecked = false}
    };

    var dayOfWeekList = new List<CronValues>
    {
         new CronValues{DayOfWeek = Convert.ToInt32(Enum.GetValues(typeof(CronValues.DaysOfWeek))),IsChecked = false}
    };

    return View(dayOfMonthList, monthList, dayOfWeekList);
}
```

Here is the model:

```
public class CronValues
{

   public enum Months
    {
        Jan = 0,
        Feb = 1,
        Mar = 2,
        Apr = 3,
        May = 4,
        Jun = 5,
        Jul = 6,
        Aug = 7,
        Sep = 8,
        Oct = 9,
        Nov = 10,
        Dec = 11
    }

  public  enum DaysOfWeek
    {
        Mon = 0,
        Tue = 1,
        Wed = 2,
        Thu = 3,
        Fri = 4,
        Sat = 5,
        Sun = 6
    }


    public int Second
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Minute
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Hour
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int DayOfMonth
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Month
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int DayOfWeek
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can not pass more than one model object to `return View`? If you want to send 3 lists to view then you should create one wrapper class and have these 3 lists as it's properties and pass that class object to the view. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use a so-called `ViewModel` for passing complex data between the controller and the view.

A possible solution for your case could look something like the following:

**IndexSchedulerViewModel**

```
public class IndexSchedulerViewModel
{
    public List<CronValues> DayOfMonthList { get; set;}
    public List<CronValues> DayOfWeekList { get; set;}
    public List<CronValues> MonthList { get; set;}
}
```

**SchedulerController**

```
CronValues cv = new CronValues();

// GET: Scheduler
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult schedulerIndex()
{
    var dayOfMonthList = new List<CronValues>
    {
        new CronValues{DayOfMonth = Convert.ToInt32(Enumerable.Range(1,31).ToList()),IsChecked = false}

    };

    var dayOfWeekList = new List<CronValues>
    {
        new CronValues{DayOfWeek = Convert.ToInt32(Enum.GetValues(typeof(CronValues.DaysOfWeek))),IsChecked = false}
    };

    var monthList = new List<CronValues>
    {
        new CronValues{DayOfMonth = Convert.ToInt32(Enum.GetValues(typeof(CronValues.Months))),IsChecked = false}
    };

    return View(new IndexSchedulerViewModel
    {
        DayOfMonthList = dayOfMonthList,
        DayOfWeekList = dayOfWeekList,
        MonthList = monthList
    });
}
```

**Index View**

```
@model YourProjectNamespace.ViewModels.IndexSchedulerViewModel

// The code below demonstrates how to access the ViewModel's properties on the view.
@Model.DayOfMonthList
@Model.DayOfWeekList
@Model.MonthList
```